# Sum of Julia Dataframe column where values of another column are in a list

Tags: arrays, dataframe, sum, julia

How do I make a line of code that works for Julia to sum the values of `col2`  where the values of  `col1`  that are in  `list` ? I'm pretty new to Julia and trying the following lines prints out the error  `Exception has occurred: DimensionMismatch DimensionMismatch: arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 10 and 3`

```
total_sum = sum(df[ismember(df[:, :col1], list), :col2])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(reshape(1:12,4,3),:auto)
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1     x2     x3    
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │     1      5      9
   2 │     2      6     10
   3 │     3      7     11
   4 │     4      8     12

julia> list = [2,3]
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 3

julia> sum(df.x2[df.x1 .∈ Ref(list)])
13
```

Uses broadcasting on `in` (how ismember is written in Julia) which can also be written as `∈`. `Ref(list)` is used to prevent broadcasting over `list`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do `filter!` is also worth knowing (using code form Dan Getz's answer):

```
julia> sum(filter!(:x1 => x1 -> x1 ∈ [2,3], df).x2)
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you're asking but try `intersect`

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a = 1:5, b = 2:6)
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1      2
   2 │     2      3
   3 │     3      4
   4 │     4      5
   5 │     5      6

julia> list = collect(3:10);

julia> sum(df.b[intersect(df.a, list)])
15
```